Scale grid gap with size of grid
I want to make these displays more responsive with grid, so I add media queries to make them shorter but in turn their gap becomes much  bigger on the grid.
How do I lessen the gap on smaller sizes?


.console-display {
  margin-top: 35rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 376px) / repeat(2, 562px);
  grid-row-gap: 5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  justify-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-container:last-child,
.image-container:last-child img {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  width: 100%
}

.image-container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* height: 376px;
    width: 562px; */

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 562px;
  color: #1a2456;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.contain {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container::after {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  content: "PRE-ORDER ";
  background-color: #ff8b68;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.head-price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.head-price span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a2456;
}

.containS {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media(max-width:1200px) {
  .image-container {
    width: 480px;
  }
  .image-container:last-child {
    width: 1077px;
  }
}
<section class="console-display">

  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="contain">
      <img src="MINI CONSOLE/1_1920x1281_crop_center.jpg.webp" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="head-price">
      <h2>MINI CONSOLE</h2><span>CA$348</span>
    </div>
    <p>Ideal for everyday shortcuts. Adaptable to any workflow</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="contain">
      <img src="MINI CONSOLE/1_1920x1281_crop_center.jpg.webp" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="head-price">
      <h2>MINI CONSOLE</h2><span>CA$348</span>
    </div>
    <p>Ideal for everyday shortcuts. Adaptable to any workflow</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="contain">
      <img src="MINI CONSOLE/1_1920x1281_crop_center.jpg.webp" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="head-price">
      <h2>MINI CONSOLE</h2><span>CA$348</span>
    </div>
    <p>Ideal for everyday shortcuts. Adaptable to any workflow</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="contain">
      <img src="MINI CONSOLE/1_1920x1281_crop_center.jpg.webp" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="head-price">
      <h2>MINI CONSOLE</h2><span>CA$348</span>
    </div>
    <p>Ideal for everyday shortcuts. Adaptable to any workflow</p>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container ">
    <div class="containS">
      <img src="MINI CONSOLE/1_1920x1281_crop_center.jpg.webp" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="head-price">
      <h2>MINI CONSOLE</h2><span>CA$348</span>
    </div>
    <p>Ideal for everyday shortcuts. Adaptable to any workflow</p>
  </div>

</section>




Why don't you just adjust the grid-gap inside the media query?

I've edited your question and removed the second question you have. Please ask one question per question post
